# Delaying execution of an async messaging function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, closures, pubnub

I have a series of lat/lng pairs that are returned from a decoded polyline.

Using `forEach` I extract each lat/lng pair and using `pubnub.publish()`, send this data to a channel.

`pubnub.publish()` is an async function and I need to delay the publishing of the message at each step through the `forEach` loop.

I have looked through a lot of answers on setTimeout executing immediately and tried different versions of the below, including, not wrapping the `setTimeout` in a closure, but am unable to delay the publish - it just sends them all as soon as it can.

Can anyone point out any glaring mistakes?

```
decodedPolyline.forEach(function (rawPoints) {

    var value = {
        lat: rawPoints[0],
        lng: rawPoints[1]
    };

    var sendmsg = function () {
        pubnub.publish({
            channel: id, 
            message: value,
            callback: function (confirmation) {
                console.log(confirmation);
            },
            error: function (puberror) {
                console.log('error: ' + puberror);
            }
        });
    };

    (function() {
        setTimeout(sendmsg, 2000);
    })();

    normalised.push(value);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to get a 2 second delay in-between each call to `pubnub.publish`? Right now, your code is queuing everything up for 2 seconds in the future, so they will all execute at about the same time after 2 seconds have passed.

Comment: @aframe The problem looks like a classic implementation of a consistent message queue.

Comment: @nderscore - I was trying to get a publish every two seconds, yes. The accepted answer did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forEach loop will be executed in near real time, meaning that all timeouts will finish almost exactly at the same time, you should increase the value of your timeout by 2000 in each iteration; Perhaps this works for you:

```
var sendmsg = function (value) {
    pubnub.publish({
        channel: id, 
        message: value,
        callback: function (confirmation) {
            console.log(confirmation);
        },
        error: function (puberror) {
            console.log('error: ' + puberror);
        }
    });
};

var timeoutVal = 2000;
decodedPolyline.forEach(function (rawPoints) {

    var value = {
        lat: rawPoints[0],
        lng: rawPoints[1]
    };

    (function(value) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            sendmsg(value);
        }, timeoutVal);
    })(value);

    //Add 2 seconds to the value so the next iteration the timeout will be executed 2 seconds after the previous one.
    timeoutVal = timeoutVal + 2000;

    normalised.push(value);
});
```

I've also moved the definition of the `sendmsg` function outside the loop. I believe it will be a little bit more performant if you dont define the function for each iteration. Hope this helps.